# Burn DICOM-compatible CD

Tags: 14.04, file-format, burning

I have some images which are in the DCM file format (DICOM image file format). I want to burn them onto a CD disk with DICOM standards  (Digital Imaging and Communications in Medicine) using Ubuntu 14.04.

How would I go about burning a DICOM-compatible CD?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I read on the German site [ubuntuusers.de](http://wiki.ubuntuusers.de/DICOM), the DCM files are just burned to the CD.

If this information is correct, you could simply burn the files to an empty CD like you would do with everything else too.

The article mentions that usually a DICOM viewer is put on the CD, too, so people from without the medicinal area can view them. THis should also work by just burning it to the disk alongside the images.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Weasis, this software can burn CD/DVD, this is the link:
[Official Site Weasis](https://dcm4che.atlassian.net/wiki/display/WEA/Home)